# p2pool manual difficulty

Tags: p2pool

I'd like to experiment with different minimum difficulty settings for my p2pool miners to see if I can get more shares per block. Does anyone have a formula or any recommendations for a minimum difficulty level, based on the GH/s available and the current share difficulty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forking p2pool and applying an adaptive difficulty patch.

My fork:
https://github.com/jramos/p2pool

Adaptive difficulty patch: https://github.com/jramos/p2pool/commit/e44dc19dada6a346628d838fa9261cd1872f493e

I'll post results of adaptive vs. non-adaptive on the fork's README page when I have a better sample.